# How to change default sound of all notifications

Tags: java, android, gradle, notifications

How i can change programatically the sound of all notifications that appear on the phone?
I don't want to create own notification, but i want to change the default system notification sound.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#NOTIFICATION_SOUND

Comment: do i have to copy the file outside the app, or i can use uri to my raw folder ?

Comment: @Natecat What if user has changed the notification ringtone, can i change it programatically again ?

Comment: Why the gradle tag? There would be nothing Gradle specific building a app that did this terrible thing.

Comment: @siemaeniu500 That code sound malicious, and I doubt you will find anyone here willing to help you with malicious code.